# Samsung Galaxy S Captivate stuck at the boot screen

Tags: boot, samsung, bootloader, odin, samsung-captivate

I have a Galaxy S Captivate and it has been problematic ever since. I flashed various stock roms (with and without bootloaders) in download mode and the phone always gets stuck at the boot screen (AT&T logo).

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zem98qpLeIs) is a video posted by someone else which shows the same problem I'm facing.

I'm guessing that I messed up the bootloader and I need to reflash/fix it somehow but can't seem find a specific targeted tutorial/guide for this issue. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.